# Вставить формулу в первую пустую ячейку и протянуть до последней строки

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim LR As Long

'до последнеи строки и столбца   
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'вставить формулу в первии пустои столбец
    Columns(lCol).Select
    Range(Cells(10, lCol + 1), Cells(10, lCol + 1)).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sas!$A$10:$AC200,MATCH(H10,Sas!N$10:N$200,0),5),0)"

'протянуть до конца 
    Range("J10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J10:J" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault

'протянуть следуищи
    Range("K10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K10:K" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault

'протянуть следуищи    
    Range("L10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L10:L" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("M10").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M10:M" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault

'столбцов будет много,потому надо штобы формула протянулась автоматищески
'то есть  "J10","K10"...заменить в переменную,никак не получяетца    
End Sub
```

Comment: Вставили формулу в первый пустой столбец. Дальше непонятно. Какую формулу писать для следующих столбцов? Столбцы J, K, L, M... - они в диапазоне ДО найденного последнего столбца или это те столбцы, в которые нужно писать формулу? Много столбцов - откуда брать это количество? Почему берем строку 10? Это первая строка таблицы?

Comment: Формула то самое,после другово нажатия она перемещается в другой пустой столбец и заполняется до последних строк "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sas!$A$10:$AC200,MATCH(H11,Sas!N$10:N$200,0),5),0)"
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Sas!$A$10:$AC200,MATCH(H12,Sas!N$10:N$200,0),5),0)" и так далее меняеца "н" индех ,да это первая строка таблицы

Comment: Например, нашли, что первый пустой столбец - J. Каким будет последний столбец для вставки формулы? Как определить, до какого столбца тянуть? Или задача другая - формулы тянуть от столбца J и до найденного последнего столбца таблицы?

Comment: последнево  столбца небудет ,надо вставлять постоянно в другой столбец после другово нажатия кнопки и заполняется до последней строки

Comment: У меня есть две таблицы, и новые данные загружаются в первую таблицу, мне нужно по коду нашли  количество, взятое в первой таблице и записать его во вторую таблицу

Answer (score 0):

Если вставка в каждый новый столбец по нажатию кнопки, не нужно в процедуре указывать все, ведь код должен обработать только один столбец.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim LR As Long, lCol As Long

    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  ' последняя строка с данными'
    lCol = Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column ' последний столбец с данными'

    ' вставить формулу в первую строку таблицы'
    Cells(10, lCol + 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sas!$A$10:$AC200,MATCH(H10,Sas!N$10:N$200,0),5),0)"

    ' протянуть формулу по строкам'
    If LR > 10 Then Cells(10, lCol + 1).Resize(LR - 9, 1).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ, формула отлично работает, и спасибо за ваше терпение

Comment: Что нужно добавить, чтобы формула имела только значения

Comment: Преобразовать формулы в значения:`Cells(10, lCol + 1).Resize(LR - 9, 1).Value = Cells(10, lCol + 1).Resize(LR - 9, 1).Value`. А правильнее, наверное, подтягивать сразу значения, без шамаства с формулами. Но это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: спасибо ,все работает